# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'check' was corrupted. while trying to read data with WinHttpReadData function

Tags: c++, winhttp

I'm trying to build an integrated browser with [winHttp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttp-sessions-overview)
and I get run time failure (stuck corruption) while I'm trying to read data.

I debugged it a lot so I have some idea about where it's happening but I'm not sure why.

I use similar idea to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpreaddata) code example.

relevant code:

> main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    WinHttpCheck check;
    char urlInput[200];
    printf("Enter url: ");
    gets_s(urlInput);
    printf("getting: %s\n", urlInput);
    check.GET(urlInput, NULL);
}
```

> WinHttpCheck.cpp

```
void WinHttpCheck::GET(const char* url, const char* extraHeaders){
...
    do // let's try to read data
    {
        // Check for available data.
        st.dwSize = 0;
        if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(st.request, &st.dwSize))
        {
            reportError("WinHttpQueryDataAvailable");
            break;
        }

        // No more available data.
        if (!st.dwSize)
            break;

        // Allocate space for the buffer.
        st.pszOutBuffer = new char[st.dwSize + 1];
        if (!st.pszOutBuffer)
        {
            reportError("zbeng_StreamStart_GET", true/*out of memory*/);
            break;
        }

        // Read data
        ZeroMemory(st.pszOutBuffer, st.dwSize + 1);

        st.bResults = WinHttpReadData(st.request, (LPVOID)st.pszOutBuffer,
                                      st.dwSize, &st.dwDownloaded);

        if (!st.bResults)
        {
            reportError("WinHttpReadData");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s", st.pszOutBuffer);
        }

        delete[] st.pszOutBuffer;

        // This condition should never be reached since WinHttpQueryDataAvailable
        // reported that there are bits to read.
        if (!st.dwDownloaded) break;
    } while (st.dwSize > 0);
...
}
```

I think there's a connection to the `check` var in `main.cpp` because if I'm changing

```
WinHttpCheck check;
```

to:

```
WinHttpCheck *check = new WinHttpCheck();
```

I have heap corruption.

extra info:

> WinHttpCheck.h

```
class WinHttpCheck
{
    ...
private:
    WinHttpSubtransport st;
}

// lpOutBuffer is the ptr for the dynamically allocated buffer
typedef struct WinHttpSubtransport 
{
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
    LPSTR pszOutBuffer = NULL;
    BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
    LPVOID lpOutBuffer = NULL;
    HINTERNET  session = NULL,
               connect = NULL,
               request = NULL;
} WinHttpSubtransport;
```

should I use global variables like in the code example? I thought maybe `ZeroMemory` or `WinHttpReadData` is getting wrong `dwSize` but I checked it and it seems alright **and there is no reported error from the function `reportError`**.

Comment: `WinHttpCheck check;` -- You didn't post the code to the constructor for this class.

Comment: no c'tor - default one. only one member - `st`

Comment: `check.GET(urlInput, NULL);` -- Where is the code to `GET`?

Comment: in WinHttpCheck.cpp. the begining it's just WinHttpOpen, WinHttpConnect, WinHttpOpenRequest exactly as this code example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttp-sessions-overview
anyway I edited this part for better explaining.

Comment: Let the debugger tell you where the memory corruption occurs.  Set a breakpoint on the first statement in main(), then Debug > New Breakpoint > Data Breakpoint and enter "check + sizeof(check)"

Comment: @HansPassant I tried but I see the curreption just at the end of `main()` but I'll try this data breakpoint. Thanks

Comment: That's entirely normal, it is only checked for corruption at the end of main().  You've got to catch it at the exact moment the corrupt write occurs, that's what a data breakpoint does.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm trying, but the VS errors out `no operator "+" matches these operands`

Comment: `LPSTR pszOutBuffer = NULL;` -- Off-topic -- You could have used `std::vector<char> pszOutbuffer` and simply call `resize()` within the loop.  That is a lot faster than continuing to call the allocator with `new[]` and `delete[]` on each iteration, and a whole lot safer.

Comment: Oops, type "&check + 1".